# ABP Text Template: Undefined Template Exception

Tags: c#, templates, abp

I'm trying to use an ABP text template to create an email message. ABP's sample code (slightly modified) works:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Volo.Abp.DependencyInjection;
using Volo.Abp.TextTemplating;

namespace TextTemplateDemo.Demos.Hello
{
    public class HelloDemo : ITransientDependency
    {
        private readonly ITemplateRenderer _templateRenderer;

        public HelloDemo(ITemplateRenderer templateRenderer)
        {
            _templateRenderer = templateRenderer;
        }

        public async Task RunAsync()
        {
            var model = new HelloModel
            {
                Name = "Test",
            };
            var result = await _templateRenderer.RenderAsync("Hello", model);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to include my own code, replacing the relevant lines of the above code:

```
            var model = new DelegateEditorRequestViewModel
            {
                BaseUrl = "Test",
                ToName = "Test",
                EntityName = "Test",
                PrivateKey = "Test",
                Message = "Test",
                FromUnit = "Test",
                FromRole = "Test",
                FromName = "Test",
            };
            var result = await _templateRenderer.RenderAsync("DelegateEditorRequestView", model);
```

I get an exception on the `RenderAsync()` call: `Volo.Abp.AbpException` with the message "Undefined template: DelegateEditorRequestView".

I'm at a loss here.

1. Is there documentation somewhere that explains how I should do this? All I've found is step-by-step, do this, then do that. But since there's no explanation, it's almost worthless. There's nothing there that I can use to understand what I should be doing, so I'm left to make blind guesses in hope of accidentally stumbling on the solution.
2. What should the first argument to `RenderAsync()` be? There doesn't appear to be any documention of this. In the example, it was the model class name without "model." But I'm getting this exception and in the absence of another explanation, the most reasonable explanation seems to be that I'm using the wrong name.
3. Finally, what's wrong with my code?

### Additional details

1. `DelegateEditorRequest.cshtml` is in the same location as `Hello.cshtml`.
2. `ConfigureServices()` includes this call:

   ```
           Configure<AbpVirtualFileSystemOptions>(options =>
           {
               options.FileSets.AddEmbedded<TextTemplateDemoModule>("TextTemplateDemo");
           });
   ```

   There's nothing that mentions the Hello example, so I presume that nothing needs to mention my class.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the template file exists in the correct location. it should have a .txt or .cshtml extension.

ABP uses the Configure method to register the template file. make sure that you registered the template in that method or in the app startup class, and it shoud look like this

```
Configure<AbpVirtualFileSystemOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileSets.AddEmbedded<YourApplicationModule>();
});
```

make sure that the template name you are passing to the RenderAsync method matches the actual template file name. the template name should be without the file extension.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `DelegateEditorRequest.cshtml` is in the same directory as the example template, `Hello.cshtml`.  The only `AddEmbedded` call in the demo project calls `TextTemplateDemoModule`. since I haven't touched that, and Hello works without being mentioned, I'm guessing that isn't the problem.